# Potential and capacity of parallel plate capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, capacitance, gauss-law

Given is a capacitor consisting of 2 sheets stretching out infinitely at $z = \frac{d}{2}$ and $z = -\frac{d}{2}$ which has a surface charge density $\sigma = \frac{Q}{\Delta F}$.

It's potential is calculated by $\Delta \phi(z) = 0$ which leads us to $\phi(z)=c_1z+c_2$. How can the constants be determined here, in other words: what are the boundary conditions for the electric potential and what are the boundary conditions for the electric field $E(z) = \nabla \phi(z)$?

Further: How can the capacity $C$ be expressed using only the surface area $\Delta F$ and $d$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now. You can choose $c_2 = 0$ and obtain $E(z) = \nabla \phi(z) = c_1$. The component of $E$ normal to a conducter like the capacitor plates satisfies $E_n(z) = E(z) = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0}$. This implies $c_1 = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0}, \phi(z) = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0}z$.

Now the Voltage $U$ is $U = \phi(\frac{d}{2}) - \phi(\frac{-d}{2}) = \frac{d\cdot Q}{\Delta F\cdot\varepsilon_0}$.
The capacity is $C = \frac{Q}{U} = \frac{\Delta F\cdot\varepsilon_0}{d}$.

Answer (score 0):

For a parallel plate capacitor the capacitance is $C=\frac{\epsilon_0\Delta F}{d}$ and the **potential difference** $V$ between the plates is given by $Q=CV$ where $Q$ is the charge enclosed in an area $\Delta F$, solving for $V$ you get $V=\frac{Q}{C}=\frac{d\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$. Now you know that the potential between the plates depends only by $z$ and is of the form $\phi(z)=c_1z+c_2$ because of the planar simmetry of the electric field  (while outside the plates is constant). The potential must satisfy $$\phi(\frac{d}{2})-\phi(-\frac{d}{2})=V$$A solution would be $\phi(z)=\frac{V}{d}(z+\frac{d}{2})$ or $\phi(z)=\frac{V}{d}z$. You can choose whatever $c_2$ you want but $c_1$ must be $\frac{V}{d}$. You are free to choose whatever boundary condition you want, but they must satisfy the identity above.